# How to get rid of the green checkmarks in my files in file explorer in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

When I go into my file explorer in Windows 10 how come next to my files there are green check marks? and what do they mean? How do I get rid of them and no I am not using Norton

Comment: Are you talking about [these](http://i.imgur.com/GnSku2I.png)? A screenshot is almost necessary..

Comment: Do those look green to you?

Answer (score 2):

When you see this checkmark, it means that the file, or files that have the checkmark on it are synchronized with Microsoft OneDrive. You can get rid of these by exiting OneDrive from the system tray.

Answer (score 0):

It is because Windows 10 comes up with One Drive and all your files get synchronized with One Drive that is why you are getting those green check boxes.

To remove the One Drive :

1. Sign in as Admin [Microsoft Account].
2. Press Start+R [Run] - -> Regedit - - > OK
3. In registry edit Go to this path - ->

   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}\ShellFolder
4. In the right pane in Attributes - -> Right Click and Modify [Decimal] - -> Change its value from

   > f080004d (4034920525)

   to

   > f090004d (4035969101)
5. Save registry and Restart your PC. It will remove your One Drive.

**Original Source :**

http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4818-onedrive-add-remove-navigation-pane-windows-10-a.html#step4